# Jquery plugin unable to get height of the image

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

i am trying to learn creating plugin from jquery plugins basic book but the following plugin does not show the height of the image it always shows 0 for image height what should i do to get image height

```
(function($) {
    jQuery.fn.gallery = function() {
        return this.each(function() {
            var e = $(this);
            console.log(e);
            var h = e.height();
            console.log(h);
            var w = e.width();
            //     e.height(40);
            //       e.width(40);
            e.click(function() {
                console.log(h);
                //    $('#gal').remove();
                e.clone().prependTo("body").center().click(function() {
                    $(this).remove();
                });

            });
        });
    };
})(jQuery);​
```

Comment: Do you use webkit? Call your plugin on `window.onload` or provide `width` and `height` to the `img` tag.

Comment: @dfsq yes i m using webkit and its works on document ready i have tried width height

Answer (score 0):

try this once

```
(function($) {
    jQuery.fn.gallery = function() {
        return this.each(function() {
            var e = $(this);
            console.log(e);
            var h = e.attr("height");
            console.log(h);
            var w = e.attr("width");              
            e.click(function() {
                console.log(h);
                //    $('#gal').remove();
                e.clone().prependTo("body").center().click(function() {
                    $(this).remove();
                });

            });
        });
    };
})(jQuery);​
```

use width and height attributes in your <img> tag
**or**

clientWidth and clientHeight are DOM properties that show the current in-browser size of the inner dimensions of a DOM element (excluding margin and border). So in the case of an IMG element, this will get the actual dimensions of the visible image.

```
var img = document.getElementById('imageid'); 
//or however you get a handle to the IMG
var width = img.clientWidth;
var height = img.clientHeight;
```